# Scale an image and move it in the middle of the screen

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

What I want to do is to reproduce the "view in Room" effect available [here](http://artsy.net/artwork/simon-roberts-bognor)

To achieve this I tried to use this jquery plugin [move.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/)

My JS function to reproduce the effect is the following:

```
var wrapperObj = $('body');
var baseImg = $('#zaza');
$('body').addClass('wrapper_wall');
/* ...hide all html elements and set a background image to the body */
var squareWidth = $(wrapperObj).width();
var squareHeight = $(wrapperObj).height();

wrapperObj.width(squareWidth + 'px');
wrapperObj.height(squareHeight + 'px');

var topCoef = 0.1;
var scaleCoef = (imgWidthDim * 680 / 95)/460;

var imgWidth = baseImg.width();
var imgHeight = baseImg.height();
var imgRedimW = imgWidth * scaleCoef;
var imgRedimH = imgHeight * scaleCoef;

imgNewXPoint = (squareWidth/2 - imgRedimW/2);
imgNewYPoint = (topCoef * squareHeight);
oldPos = baseImg.offset();
$('#zaza').css('box-shadow', '0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)');
console.log('old pos left: ' + oldPos.left);
console.log('new pos left: ' + imgNewXPoint);
console.log('move to: ' + (imgNewXPoint - oldPos.left));
move('#zaza')
    .translate(imgNewXPoint - oldPos.left, imgNewYPoint - oldPos.top)
    .scale(scaleCoef)
    .duration('2s')
    .end(function(){
        console.log('end transition');
        $('a#bts').css('display', 'block');
        $('a.wall_view').addClass('on-the-wall');
        newPos = $('#zaza').offset();
    });
```

Ok. So, my problem here is I can`t center the image (baseImg) in the middle of the screen(body -> wrapperObj);

Comment: I'm not quite sure the effect your going for, but this might help: http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-lighter/

Comment: It`s a requirement for me to reproduce that effect.

Comment: nobody any idea. I`m not sure the scale effect working fine..:(

Comment: I will have some time in the next couple of days, if you still need a hand

Comment: my test subdomain, with a real example, is here: http://test.hyphengallery.ro/image-nature-2-56 . Click on the "price" button  and click again on "view on the wall"